# Java Syntax Checker using java.util.stack

Tags: java, file-io, stack

I have an assignment with regards to making a Java syntax checker. It is using java.util.stack, and what it's supposed to do is read from a file that's provided and then check for syntax errors. How it is supposed to do this is by adding a 'token' to the stack that has the character, line number, position in the line, whether it's unmatched or unexpected and the line itself.

The code for the function is as follows:

```
    public static boolean check(String Filename, boolean ConsoleOutput) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        mFileName = Filename;
        mConsoleOutput = ConsoleOutput;
        File mFile = new File("src/Kurien/tests/" + mFileName);
        Scanner FileReader = new Scanner(mFile);
        if(ConsoleOutput)
        {
            System.out.println("Processing " + "'" + mFileName + "'" + "\n" + "----------------------");
        }
        while (FileReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            mLineNumber++;
            mLine = FileReader.nextLine();
            for (int counter = 0; counter < mLine.length(); counter++)
            {
                mCharacter = mLine.charAt(counter);
                if (mCharacter == '(')
                {
                    mStack.push(new Token(mCharacter, mLineNumber, counter, ErrorDetail.Unmatched, mLine));
                }
                else if (mCharacter == '{')
                {
                    mStack.push(new Token(mCharacter, mLineNumber, counter, ErrorDetail.Unmatched, mLine));
                }
                else if (mCharacter == ')')
                {
                    if (mStack.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Error = true;
                        mStack.push(new Token(mCharacter, mLineNumber, counter, ErrorDetail.Unexpected, mLine));
                    }
                    else if (mStack.peek().equals('('))
                    {
                        mStack.pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error = true;
                        mStack.push(new Token(mCharacter, mLineNumber, counter, ErrorDetail.Unexpected, mLine));
                    }
                }
                else if (mCharacter == '}')
                {
                    if (mStack.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Error = true;
                        mStack.push(new Token(mCharacter, mLineNumber, counter, ErrorDetail.Unexpected, mLine));
                    }
                    else if (mStack.peek().equals('{'))
                    {
                        mStack.pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error = true;
                        mStack.push(new Token(mCharacter, mLineNumber, counter, ErrorDetail.Unexpected,mLine));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!Error)
        {
            System.out.println("[SUCCESS]");
        }
        else
        {
            while(mStack.iterator().hasNext())
            {
                Token Temp = (Token)mStack.iterator().next();
                if(Temp.mDetail == ErrorDetail.Unexpected)
                {
                    System.out.println("[ERROR] " + Temp.mDetail.toString() + " closing token in file '" + mFileName + "'" + " line#" + Temp.mLineNumber);
                    System.out.println(mLine);
                    System.out.println(Spaces(Temp.mLine.length() - Temp.mPosition) + "^");

                }
                else if(Temp.mDetail == ErrorDetail.Unmatched)
                {
                    System.out.println("[ERROR] + " + Temp.mDetail + "token in file '" + mFileName + "'" + "line#" + Temp.mLineNumber);
                    System.out.println(mLine);
                    System.out.println(Spaces(Temp.mLine.length() - Temp.mPosition) + "^");
                }
            }
        }
        return Error;
    }

    private static class Token
    {
        char mCharacter;
        int mLineNumber;
        int mPosition;
        ErrorDetail mDetail;
        String mLine;

        Token(char Character, int LineNumber, int Position, ErrorDetail Detail, String Line)
        {
            mCharacter = Character;
            mLineNumber = LineNumber;
            mPosition = Position;
            mDetail = Detail;
            mLine = Line;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the expected output for the first test case is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Unexpected closing token in file 'test1.txt' line#7:
}
^
```

However all I get is the following:

```
[ERROR] + Unmatchedtoken in file 'test1.txt'line#1
```

I know the formatting could be fine tuned, however there is clearly another problem here that I just can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: In case of, if that this is not "only" an exercise: you are aware of http://javaparser.org/ ? works for me like a charm. the open source project is on GitHub.

Comment: I have trimmed it down as much as I think I can without losing potentially problematic code.